# Is the following operation legal within the $\sup$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vector-spaces, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose I have two vectors $z, x$ of equal size, and $|x| \leq 1$

I know the following is true:

$$\sum_iz_ix_i \leq |\sum_i z_ix_i| \leq \sum_i|z_ix_i|$$

is it legal to write the following:

$\sup_x \{ \sum_iz_ix_i\} = \sup_x \{|\sum_i z_ix_i|\} = \sup_x \{\sum_i|z_ix_i|\}$?

Why or why not.

Comment: Are there constraints on $x$? If not then all three suprema are either $0$ (if $z = 0$) or infinite (if $z \neq 0$), which is probably not what you meant...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Oh yes there is, I edited the question, but are they equal and what is the reasoning there?

Comment: In my country, all inequalities are legal. I'm not sure about other countries though :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: If $z = 0$, all three suprema are $0$; otherwise, what unit vector $x$ (in terms of $z$) maximizes $\langle x, z\rangle = \sum_{i} x_{i} z_{i}$, and what is the maximum value?

Comment: Take $x = z/|z|$, but how does that help in proving the inequality?

Comment: If $\tilde{z}$ denotes the vector whose $i$th component is $|z_{i}|$, you can make the corresponding analysis for $\tilde{z}$; what is the maximum value, and how the two maximum values related? :)